# Is there any way to download Office 2010 legally?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010

I would like to reinstall my PC, but I lost al my install CD's. However, I still have the product key for Office 2010 Professional Plus. Is there any place where I can download Office 2010 Professional Plus safely and legally? I did some research on the internet, but all links direct me to 2013.

Comment: Just download the "untouched" media from a torrent site. [The EULA](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13653) goes on about restrictions placed on you when you have the media, not that you can't re-acquire it from a third-party source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be download links in forums, just google "Office 2010 EditionHere LEGAL download" in my experience, Microsoft just removes the links and pages for the downloads, they're still sitting on a server somewhere, waiting for someone to dust them off.

Comment: Found a website with direct links to Office 2010. Thanks for your tip! http://www.tech.sc/download-microsoft-office-2010-free-legally/

Comment: Obviously MS no longer wants to allow people to download install media. It may take a while to for them to kill all the links, but they will eventually.

Answer (score 0):

MS seems to have removed all the download pages for 2010 and redirected them to the download pages for 2013. So simply downloading a replacement install is no longer possible (legally). Illegal routes exist, but this is the wrong place to explore them.

Microsoft will send you replacement media if you provide "proof of purchase". Don't know if possessing a valid product key counts. You'll need to contact them as explained here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326246

Comment: OK, somebody downvoted this, which means they have reason to believe I got my facts wrong somehow. Care to share?

Comment: The unexplained downvotes on this answer are just a little childish. You can always find unauthorized sources for data, but so what? I'm just pointing out the authorized channel.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a legal key already, this site works (at least for 2010 that I need)
https://office2010.getmicrosoftkey.com/  I just spent 20 minutes on support with Microsoft to get it.